# Como usar uma Masked textbox para tempo em C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, textbox

Estou tentando criar uma **masked textbox** que recebe o tempo de um vídeo. Mas não sei como formatar a **masked textbox** para que receba o tempo em **HH:MM:SS:MMM**.
O valor do tempo que obtenho do vídeo é um *double*.
1 seg = 1000.
É um Windows Form

Comment: É Windows Forms ou WPF?

Comment: é um Windows Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar um [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) e adicionar uma `Custom Mask` para ele.

Acho que uma imagem explica melhor, então basta fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer dúvida pode olhar essas referências abaixo:

- [MaskedTextBox in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/)
- [Apresentando e usando o controle MaskedTextBox](http://www.macoratti.net/14/09/c_masked.htm)

#### Edição após comentário

Se você deseja validar o valor, existe algumas formas de fazer isso no `TextBox`, mas eu aconselho usar o `DateTimePicker`, que já existe. Utilizando ele, basta adicionar um `Custom Format` em propriedades. Ficaria desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas ai ele vai poder adicionar qualquer valor, mesmo que seja um horário inválido. Exemplo: `90:80:45`.